# Magento 2 : Language and currency default

Tags: magento2, language

I have create two custom field like language & currency while register customer has to enter that field.

After, login customer have to get pages in what language and currency he had entered in registration.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create an event observer for customer_login and get the post values of your registration form there.

Set these values for CurrencyCode

```
$this->_storeManager->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode('EUR');
```

and for the Language in your observer.

```
$this->_store->setLocaleCode('de_DE');
```

Comment: Hi thank you, I am not able setLcalecode() in magento 2.2.2